# Custom model for authentication in django restframework instead of default user model

Tags: django, rest, authentication, frameworks

I want to do some custom auth for my users with username or email with password. At the first time of logging with email and password the api should return me the respective user token. For all other operations with the api I need to make use of token, which I get at time of login.

And I need a custom model to store all user info like username, password, phone, email, token etc.

How to achieve this in django restframework.

Please guide me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try django custom authentication https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django rest-framework has a built in token system which can be used to distribute and authenticate tokens. Below is a sample of how to use it.

**Create TOKEN**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
user = User.objects.get(pk=some_pk)
token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
```

**Authenticate token**

```
if Token.ojects.get(key=token) # token is sent by client side 
    # do some task as auth is successful
```

If you want to extend the default User model then create a new model and put a onetoone field in your custom model which references default User model.

```
class AppUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ... # add other custom fields like address or phone
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Arpit Solanki.